# How do I select and use a BJT in a simple LED circuit?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I am trying to understand how to use a transistor in a simple LED circuit.

The LED (blue) has a forward voltage of 3V, and I'd like to provide it with 19-20mA. VCC on the circuit is 3.3V. I was thinking I could connect VCC to the collector terminal, and the cathode of the LED to the emitter terminal. I have a 3.3V signal with a maximum current of 10mA. I want to connect this signal to the base terminal of the transistor to illuminate the blue LED.

From what I have heard, an NPN might be a good fit for this application. However, I am struggling to understand how an NPN BJT works, and how to confirm that it meets the circuit requirements.

I have a few questions:

1. How do I determine if a transistor will operate at a given voltage (3.3V)? I see maximum voltages listed, but not minimums.
2. How do I determine the required current on the base terminal to “close / enable” the transistor?
3. How do I determine at what voltage on the base terminal will the transistor be “open / disabled?”
4. Do I use DC Current Gain to calculate how the ratio of current on the base terminal to the current through the collector to emitter terminals? If so, how?
5. Is VCE the voltage drop over the device?
6. Is VCCSAT the voltage drop over the device when the device is saturated?

I am new to EE; any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

I was asked to include the transistor part number and a link to the datasheet. This is the one I am looking at, but I'm not sure it is correct for my application: [BC847BLT3G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc846alt1-d.pdf)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the part number and link  the datasheet for the transistor you are using?

Comment: @Pxl Added. I'm not sure that this transistor meets my needs, though.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the blue LED? Using 3.3V for driving blue LEDs leaves very little room for controlling the current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Transistors don't have minimum voltage requirements per se, the limiting factor is generally the base emitter voltage \$V_{BE}\$ which is around 0.6 V for a silicon transistor.
2. For saturation, you'll want something like 1/10th the collector
   current.
3. The transistor will be 'on' when the voltage from base to emitter is at least the \$V_{BE}\$ for the transistor.
4. You don't use the DC current gain when working with transistors in saturation, that will underestimate the needed base current. Usually you use the \$I_C/10\$ rule of thumb to ensure plenty of base current.
5. \$V_{CE}\$ is the voltage from collector to emitter, so yes, the voltage across the device.
6. I believe you mean \$V_{CE_{sat}}\$ which is the voltage from collector to emitter when the transistor is in saturation. This is basically the minimum voltage drop you can expect the transistor to have.

Running a blue LED on 3.3V and keeping the current at a given point is going to be iffy, you don't have much headroom on the voltage, and the LED's forward voltage can vary from device to device and with temperature.

Let's say you wanted to get 20 mA through an LED with a \$V_F\$ of 3.0 V from a 3.3 V source. You would calculate the current limiting resistor to drop the extra 0.3 V, so $$\frac{0.3 V}{20 mA} = 15\Omega$$

Now say that \$V_F\$ changes due to temperature or device variability and it's now 3.1 V. With a 15\$\Omega\$ resistor you would have $$\frac{0.2V}{15\Omega} = 13.333 mA$$ not quite the 20 mA you were expecting. Adding in the \$V_{CE_{sat}}\$ of a transistor gives you even less leeway.

Running from a higher voltage makes LED \$V_F\$ changes less critical,let's say you used a 5 V supply for the LED. To get 20 mA you would need $$\frac{2 V}{20 mA} = 100\Omega$$
If \$V_F\$ increases to 3.1 V it's now $$\frac{1.9 V}{100\Omega} = 19 mA$$
much better than the 13.333 mA in the previous example.

Using a transistor you can run the LED on a higher voltage than the I/O voltage, like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzhuu6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you already have a higher voltage supply available you can use that, if not you can use a DC-DC converter to boost the 3.3 V to obtain the higher voltage for the LED.

If you just want the LED to light, and it's a one-off project you can try running it at 3.3 V, same basic circuit. Instead of the 100\$\Omega\$ a 10 to 15\$\Omega\$ limiting resistor in series with the LED should be about right. It might work well enough for your purposes.